# I have a problem converting an int to a String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, variables

I have a saved card in an asset file like this:

[image]
I get two cards in my simulator:

[image]

I get two cards 6❤️ and 2❤️.

In debug mode `leftNumber` does not equal 6, and rightNumber does not equal 2.

Example: `leftNumber` is equal 3. When the simulator executes line `leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(leftNumber)")`, it doesn't show `card3`, `card4` or other cards.

```
 @IBAction func dealButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let leftNumber = Int.random(in: 2...14) 
        let rightNumber = Int.random(in: 2...14)

        leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(leftNumber)") //here is problem
        rightImageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(rightNumber)") //here is problem

    if leftNumber > rightNumber {
        leftScore+=1
        leftScoreLabel.text = String(leftScore)
    }
    else if leftNumber < rightNumber {
        rightScore+=1
        rightScoreLabel.text = String (rightScore)
    } else {

    }
}`
```

I have tried to solution this problem like this, but isn't working

```
leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(String(leftNumber))")
```

Comment: have you tried: 
UIImage(named: "card" + String(leftNumber)) 
?

Comment: I tried too and it doesn’t work

Comment: try creating names in let and give them in UIimage...like: let leftImageName = "card\(leftNumber)" let rightImageName = "card\(rightNumber)" ..... leftImageView.image = UIImage(named: leftImageName) .... I see no issue but you can try this once.

Comment: I tried, but it also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
  let int = Int.random(in: 1..<3)
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 120, width: 353, height: 400)
      imageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(int)")
      imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
      imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      view.addSubview(imageView)
}
```